# Need to Draw a box view as per the row counts in Listview Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a Grouping listview which will group by years and inside each group there would months to display but along with that i need to draw a boxview as you can see in the below image this is where i am stuck so please can anybody tell me what approach should i use to achieve such layout

This is what i am trying to achieve

[image: this is what i am trying to achieve]

till now i was able to get this

[image]

just the missing piece right now is the line in the left side starts from the header of listview

My Xaml :

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name ="lstView" IsGroupingEnabled="true" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding LongName}" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding ShortName}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#customizing-grouping

Comment: Use this code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#customizing-grouping as @ Lucas Zhang - MSFT said and at the header place a StackLayout and inside the StackLayout put the year and an image (the blue cicle image), and inside the Content, place a StackLayout too, but with the <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label> and an image (blue column). If you want a white background set the backgroundcolor property of the StackLayout and so on.

Comment: @BenceLénárt i was able to create that thanks